# A custom tokenizer for Java

Tags: java, token, tokenize, text-processing, text-analysis

I am developing an application in which I need to process text files containing emails. I need all the tokens from the text and the following is the definition of token:

1. Alphanumeric
2. Case-sensitive (case to be preserved)
3. '!' and '$' are to be considered as constituent characters. Ex: `FREE!!`, `$50` are tokens
4. '.' (dot) and ',' comma are to be considered as constituent characters if they occur between numbers. For ex:

   192.168.1.1, $24,500

   are tokens.

and so on..

Please suggest me some open-source tokenizers for Java which are easy to customize to suit my needs. Will simply using StringTokenizer and regex be enough? I have to perform stopping also and that's why I was looking for an open source tokenizer which will also perform some extra things like stopping, stemming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few comments up front:

- From [StringTokenizer javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html):

> StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility
>   reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended
>   that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String
>   or the java.util.regex package instead.

- Always [use Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=open-source+tokenizers+for+Java) first - the first result as of now is [JTopas](http://jtopas.sourceforge.net/jtopas/index.html). I did not use it, but it looks it could work for this

As for regex, it really depends on your requirements. Given the above, this might work:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Mkt {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([$\\d.,]+)|([\\w\\d!$]+)");
    String str = "--- FREE!! $50 192.168.1.1 $24,500";
    System.out.println("input: " + str);

    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    while(m.find()) {
      System.out.println("token: " + m.group());
    }
  }
}
```

Here's a sample run:

```
$ javac Mkt.java && java Mkt
input: --- FREE!! $50 192.168.1.1 $24,500
token: FREE!!
token: $50
token: 192.168.1.1
token: $24,500
```

Now, you might need to tweak the regex, for example:

- You gave `$24,500` as an example. Should this work for `$24,500abc` or `$24,500EUR`?
- You mentioned `192.168.1.1` should be included. Should it also include `192,168.1,1` (given `.` and `,` are to be included)?

and I guess there are other things to consider.

Hope this helps to get you started.